# Creating Two Identical, But Distinct, Decks of Cards, And Simultaneously Drawing From Both

Tags: java

I am utilizing the standard array-driven approach to creating, shuffling, and drawing a 52-card deck of standard playing cards. My challenge is coming in the form of having two identical, but distinct, decks drawing simultaneously, side-by-side.

Originally I thought having two instances of the class Deck in the executable DeckDrawTest class would be sufficient, but when I asked for the class to draw 104 (52 x 2) times, I got all 52 cards of one deck and 52 null entries. I then made a duplicate Deck class called Deck2, and changed all the method and variable names while keeping the functionality the same - no dice, same results. I then tried to overcome a potential multiple inheritance problem by duplicating the Card class that both Deck and Deck2 drew from, making another class identical to Card called Card2 but with different variable names. Has not changed the outcome. Code is presented below.

Card

```
public class Card
{
    private final String name;

    private final String suit;

    public Card(String cardName, String cardSuit) {
        this.name = cardName;
        this.suit = cardSuit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + "of " + suit;
    }

}
```

`Deck2` (which draws from `Card` for now, will fix names once I get it functional):

```
public class Deck2
{
    private static final SecureRandom randomClam = new SecureRandom();
    private static final int DECKSIZE2 = 52;

    private Card[] deck = new Card[DECKSIZE2];
    private int currentCard = 0;

    public Deck2() {
        String[] names2 = {"A ", "2 ", "3 ","4 ", "5 ", "6 ", "7 ", "8 ", "9 ", "10 ", "J ", "Q ", "K "};
        String[] suits2 = {"♠ ", "♥ ", "♣ ", "♦ "};

        for (int count = 0; count < deck.length; count ++) {
            deck[count] =
                new Card(names2[count % 13], suits2[count /13]);
        }

    }

    public void shuffle2() {
        currentCard = 0;

        for (int first2 = 0; first2 < deck.length; first2++) {
            int second2 = randomClam.nextInt(DECKSIZE2);

            Card temp2 = deck[first2];
            deck[first2] = deck[second2];
            deck[second2] = temp2;
        }

    }

    public Card dealCard(){
        if (currentCard < deck.length) {
            return deck[currentCard++];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

`DeckDrawTest` (which is drawing from `Deck` and `Deck2`)

```
public class DeckDrawTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck myDeck = new Deck();
        myDeck.shuffle();
        Deck2 yourDeck = new Deck2();
        yourDeck.shuffle2();

        for(int i = 1; i <=104; i++){
            System.out.printf("%-20s", myDeck.dealCard(), "%-20s", yourDeck.dealCard());
            if(i %2 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

So how do I get this program to draw from two distinct, but identical, decks, instead of just drawing from one?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "identical but distinct". These two words seem to be antonyms to me, how can two objects be identical and distinct at the same time?

Comment: so, same decks with same cards in the same order, but when I draw one card from deck1, it doesn't change deck2? why don't you just copy Deck2.deck?

Comment: The two decks contain the same cards (ace of spades through 2 of diamonds, etc) but are distinct objects from one another. Like if I draw from myDeck and I get the 9 of clubs, I won't be able to draw 9 of clubs again from myDeck, but I could get it from yourDeck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `i` goes up to 104, but in each loop you call `dealCard` on both decks. That's where the `null` values come from. You only need to loop up to 52:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=52; i++) {
```

Your output using `printf` is wrong, the function only expects one formatter. Your version just outputs the value of `myDeck.dealCard()` and also calls (but not uses) `yourDeck.dealCard()`. To create a line with the output of both calls, use something like this:

```
 System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s", myDeck.dealCard(), yourDeck.dealCard());
```

Comment: Ah, that helped out. I just need more practice working with printf. And I also fixed it so I do get two distinct columns!

Comment: Nice. By the way, you only need one `Deck` class. I just saw that you are a new user on Stack Overflow - welcome :) If my answer solved your question, just click the little check mark next to my answer